# How do I find out what processes are accessing the SPECIFIC hard disk in Linux?

Tags: linux, hard-drive, performance

I have several hard drives and power save does not work for them. I would like to know, which process are probably accessing them.

But I need to know this BY DRIVE, i.e. the thing what apparently `iotop` can't do.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know of an application that lists process io by disk. You may try using a combination of `atop` and `iostat`
Press "D" within `atop` to get a disk utilization view.
`iostat` can monitor per disk bandwidth utilization